# Xamarin: ICommand is this related to Command Pattern

Tags: xamarin, icommand, command-pattern

Hello I am working a drawing application which allow user to draw strokes to the screen using Xamarin Form. Function I will need is: Add, Remove, Clear, and Undo. In xamarin, there is an interface called ICommand, but it only Execute method and have no unexecute related function. If I need to do a undo command, I will have to stored all those command and pop then call the unexecute the command again. Does ICommand is part of the command pattern or a completely different thing.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Command/

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Windows.Input.ICommand/

Answer (score 1):

The `ICommand` helps you implement the Command patterns in your app. We have an implementation in Xamarin.Forms called [`Xamarin.Forms.Command`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Command/) that you can use

The command pattern by definition does not maintain the stack of executed commands, but it helps you to do that to implement `undo` feature. (ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern#Uses)

Comment: So it make sense to extend that ICommand and have interface function called UnExecute.